# The second root of a number is up to four digits without decomposing it

Tags: python

I want to calculate the root of a number up to four decimal places without rendering and I use the following code but I can not print out the output without rendering the output.

```
import math
num = float(input('Enter a number: '))
num_sqrt = math.sqrt(num)
print('The square root of %0.4f is %0.4f'%(num ,num_sqrt))
```

For example, if the inputs are as follows:

```
1
2
3
19
```

The output should be as follows:

```
1.0000
1.4142
1.7320
4.3588
```

Comment: whats the error ? it works just fine for me..!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by rendering. What do you mean by decomposing?

Comment: So you only want to print the square root? What's wrong with `print("{:.4f}".format(num_sqrt))`?

Comment: Without rounding the number

Comment: The result shouldn't be rounded, as you are using `sqrt()`!

Comment: I updated the code at the top

Comment: The exact sqrt of these numbers (besides 1) have more than 4 decimal places (they are irrational), so you have to round.

Comment: What would the expected result then be for `sqrt(2)`, whose decimal expansion is infinite? Its IEEE 754 representation, or something like that?

Comment: My problem with this code is that the root of the second is rounded.

Comment: @fuglede: Expansion stops for me on sqrt(2) at 54 digits (1.4142135623730951454746218587388284504413604736328125)

Comment: @l'L'l Python's `float` is the collection of double precision floating points (see e.g. [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)); any irrational number, such as sqrt(2), has infinite decimal expansion (and no irrational number is representable as a double precision `float`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're printing only 4 decimals and you don't want the number rounded that means you want the decimals truncated and regular formatting methods don't provide facilities for that.

You can easily achieve that if you pre-process your number as:

```
def truncate_number(number, decimals):
    factor = 10.0 ** decimals
    return int(number * factor) / factor

num = float(input('Enter a number: '))
num_sqrt = num ** 0.5  # or math.sqrt(num)  if that's what you prefer.
print("The square root of {:.4f} is {:.4f}".format(num, truncate_number(num_sqrt, 4)))
```

It essentially just multiplies the number with `10^number_of_decimals`, truncates the decimals by converting it to an `int` and then divides it with the same multiplication factor - this, in effect, leaves only the decimals you're interested in.

You don't even nedd to use formatting directives after pre-processing your number as Python won't print trailing zeros so a simple `print("The square root of {} is {}".format(num, truncate_number(num_sqrt, 4)))` should suffice.

Comment: Can you write a math library too?

Comment: @BitaJafarzadeh - You mean `math.sqrt(num)` instead of `num ** 0.5`? Sure, those two are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all answers to have four decimal places, you can use .format as in...

```
import math
num = float(input('Enter a number: '))
num_sqrt = math.sqrt(num)
print('The square root of {} is {:0.4f}'.format(num, num_sqrt))
```

notice the {:0.4f} in the print statment

- : introduces the format spec
- 0 enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types
- .4 sets the precision to 4
- f displays the number as a fixed-point number

Comment: @BitaJafarzadeh  writing a new math library is possible but why?   I suppose if one wanted to increase their Python skills it may be a good exercise.